# Facebook stalls with LOADING via Apps> AppName> Promote> iOS Feed for Customizing Ad

Tags: facebook

We cannot proceed past the stage of hitting the "Customize Ad" button when trying to create an ad in Facebook for an iOS app?

A sample ad appears showing the 800x100 banner we created for our Facebook App, yet this is not suitable for the Facebook iOS ad, so we select the "Customize Ad" button, and the "Loading..." dialogue pops up. But it simply hangs there and does not proceed to the Customize Ad section of the process.

Is it that the Facebook servers are just that busy, or could something else be the matter? We have tried this on several occasional via multiple browsers.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any resolutions?